# Translation from Binary to Decimal

Tags: binary

How does one translate the following binary to Decimal. And yes the decimal points are with the whole binary value

```
1) 101.011
b) .111
```

Comment: http://www.binaryhexadecimal.com/conversion/binary-to-decimal-converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 101.011

> = 2*2^-3 + 1*2^-2 + 0*2^-1 + 1*2^0 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^2
>
> = (1/8) + (1/4) + 0 + 1 + 0 + 4
>
> = 5.375

2) .111

> = 1*2^-3 + 1*2^-2 + 1*2^-1
>
> = (1/8) + (1/4) + (1/2)
>
> = .875

Answer (score 1):

Each `1` corresponds to a power of 2, the power used is based on the placement of the `1`:

```
101.011
  = 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 + 0*2^-1 + 1*2^-2 + 2*2^-3
  = 1*4 + 1*1 + 1/4 + 1/8
  = 5.375

.111 
  = 1*2^-1 + 1*2^-2 + 1*2^-3
  = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8
  = .875
```

If you don't like dealing with the decimal point you can always left shift by multiplying by a power of 2:

```
101.011 * 2^3 = 101011
```

Then convert that to decimal and, since you multiplied by `2^3 = 8`, divide the result by `8` to get your answer. `101011` converts to `43` and `43/8 = 5.375`.

Comment: Thanx man. Only one question? is it the same technique that works when lets say i have C.4 base 16?

Comment: @HakimMarley Yeah, same thing works just remember in base 16 you need to use `16` everywhere instead of `2`. If you use the shift trick that means `C.4 * 16 = C4`, so `C*16 + 4 = 12*16 + 4 = 196`, which means that `C.4 = 196/16 = 12.25`

Answer (score 0):

`101.011` should be converted like below

```
(101) base2 = (2^0 + 2^2) = (1 + 4) = (5) base10

(.011) base2 = 0/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 = 3/8
```

So in total the decimal conversion would be

```
5 3/8 = 5.375
```

Comment: Yes its valid...its 101.011. Its pretty much like converting 528.31 base 10 to binary

Comment: The answer is 5,375 base 10. But am still wondering how on earth we got there

Comment: @HakimMarley, look at the edit in answer if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Decimal numbers cannot be represented in binary. It has to be whole numbers.

Here is a simple system

Let's take your binary number for example.

```
101011
```

Every position represents a power of 2. With the left-most position representing the highest power of 2s. To visualize this, we can do the following.

```
 1      0     1      0       1      1
 2 ^ 6  2 ^ 5 2 ^ 4  2 ^ 3   2 ^ 2  2 ^ 1
```

We go by each position and do this math

```
1 * (2 ^6 ) + 0 * (2 ^ 5) + 1 * (2 ^ 4) + 0 * (2 ^ 3) + 1 * (2 ^ 2) + 1 * (2 ^ 1)
```

Doing the math gives us

```
(1 * 64) + (0 * 32) + (1 * 16) + (0 * 8) + (1 * 4) + (1 * 2) =
64 + 0 + 16 + 0 + 4 + 2 = 86
```

We get an answer of `86` this way.

Comment: The answer is 5,375 base 10. But am still wondering how on earth we got there

Comment: decimals are invalid in binary

Comment: @RichardHamilton Decimals aren't invalid in binary, they follow the same rules as digits before the decimal point `(2^position)`.

Comment: @RichardHamilton In practice too. Most of the bits in an IEEE float are allocated to the mantissa which is interpreted as a fractional number between 0 and 1 (ignoring the implicit leading `1.`)

Comment: @RichardHamilton and you can always left shift a binary number by multiplying by a power of 2, so if you really don't like the decimal you can multiply `101.011` by `2^3 = 8` and then convert `101011` to decimal and divide the result by 8 again you'll get the right answer. `101011` in binary is 43 in decimal, not `86`. You should have started at `2^0` not `2^1`.